# How can I listen all global key press events from my app running in the background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I'm trying to develop a flutter desktop app which automatically tracks how we spend time on our devices. How can I listen all global key press events from my app running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create like a service for it, you can try some lib in [C with ffi](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop) or run a [process](https://pub.dev/packages/process_run) like a python or java program.